# How to redirect it to the same component from the component in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have one component called **ListEnterprise** which is responsible for rendering and displaying data from the database. On this component, I am calling another component **AddEnterprise** to for the POST request to update the data into the database and redirecting it to **ListEnterprise** component to render the updated data. Data is updating in the database, but redirection is not happening.

Basically, I am on the **ListEnteprise** component, calls AddEnterprise component and trying to redirect it to **ListEnterprise** which is not happening.

**Note:-** When I tried redirecting to some other component lets say Home("/"). It is working fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

**ListEnterprise**

```
class ListEnterprises extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            enterprises: [],
            message: null,
            showFormMessage: false,
        }
        //Any method in a react component should be bound to this
        this.refreshEnterprises = this.refreshEnterprises.bind(this);
    }

    // After all the elements of the page is rendered correctly, this method is called.
    // After the markup is set on the page, this technique called by React itself to either fetch the data from An External API or perform some unique operations which need the JSX.API
    // componentDidMount() method is the perfect place, where we can call the setState() method to change the state of our application and render() the updated data loaded JSX. For example, we are going to fetch any data from an API then API call should be placed in this lifecycle method,
    // and then we get the response, we can call the setState() method and render the element with updated data.
    //React defines a component lifecycle. componentDidMount will be called as soon as the component is mounted. We are calling refreshCourses as soon as a component is mounted.
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshEnterprises();
    }

    _showMessage = (bool) => {
        this.setState({
            showFormMessage: bool
        });
    }

    refreshEnterprises() {
        EnterpriseService.retrieveAllEnterprises()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.setState({ enterprises: response.data, isLoading: false });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    removeEnterprise(id) {
        EnterpriseService.deleteEnterprise(id)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                let updatedEnterprises = [...this.state.enterprises].filter(i => i.id !== id);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    render() {
        console.log("Rendering Enterprises");

        if (this.state.isLoading)
            return (<div>Loading...</div>);

        return (
            <div key={this.props.location.pathname}>
                <NavigationComponent /><br /><br />
                <h3 align="center">Here are all your Enterprises</h3><br />
                {this.state.message && <div class="alert alert-success">{this.state.message}</div>}
                <Container>
                    <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Enterprise</th>
                                <th>Industry</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Update</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.enterprises.map(
                                    enterprise =>
                                        <tr key={enterprise.id}>
                                            <td>{enterprise.enterpriseName}</td>
                                            <td>{enterprise.industry}</td>
                                            <td>{enterprise.description}</td>
                                            <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.updateEnterprise(enterprise.id)} >Update</button></td>
                                            <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.removeEnterprise(enterprise.id)}>Delete</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Container>{" "}{" "}{" "}

                <div className="container">
                    <Button color="primary" size="lg" onClick={this._showMessage.bind(null, true)}>Add Enterprise</Button>{' '}
                    <Button color="secondary" size="lg" onClick={this._showMessage.bind(null, false)}>Hide</Button>{' '}
                    {/* {this.state.showFormMessage && (<AddEnterprise {...this.props} containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />)} */}
                    {/* /console.log(this.props); */}
                    {this.state.showFormMessage && (<AddEnterprise  {...this.props} />)}
                </div>
                <FooterComponent />
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default ListEnterprises;
```

**AddEnterprise**

```
class AddEnterprise extends Component {

    emptyEnterprise = {
        enterpriseName: "",
        industry: "",
        description: ""
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            isForm: false,
            enterprisePayload: this.emptyEnterprise
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.addEnterprise = this.addEnterprise.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;

        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        let updatedEnterprisePayload = { ...this.state.enterprisePayload };
        updatedEnterprisePayload[name] = value;
        this.setState({ enterprisePayload: updatedEnterprisePayload });
        console.log(updatedEnterprisePayload);
    }

    addEnterprise(event) {
        const payload = this.state.enterprisePayload;
        EnterpriseService.addEnterprise(payload)
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ isLoading: false, isForm: true });
                //event.peventDefault();
                this.props.history.push("/enterprises");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.isLoading && this.state.isForm)
            return (<div>Loading...</div>);

        return (
            <div className="base-container">
                <div className="header"><div><br />Add Enterprise</div></div>
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="form">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="enterpriseName" for="enterpriseName">Enterprise Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="enterpriseName" id="enterpriseName" placeholder="enterpriseName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="industry" for="industry">Industry</label>
                            <input type="text" name="industry" id="industry" placeholder="industry" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="description" for="description">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="description" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.addEnterprise}>Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
//export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AddEnterprise));
export default AddEnterprise;
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {}
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
          <Route path="/enter" exact={true} component={EnterSystem} />
          <Route path="/enterprises" exact={true} component={ListEnterprises} />
          // {/* <Route path='/categories' exact={true} component={Category} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/expenses' exact={true} component={Expenses} /> */}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use redux ?

Comment: No..simply trying to redirect using   this.props.history.push("/enterprises");

Comment: As I understand, your AddEnterprise component is kind of a modal for show a form, not a whole page, right ? And after adding a new enterprise, you need the refresh the EnterPriseList component to get the new data ?

Comment: Yes, its not a Whole page. Its just a separate component which comes to ListEnterprise when I click AddEnterprise button in ListEnterprise component.

Comment: You will need to perform the refresh(`refreshEnterprises`) in `componentDidUpdate`, also will need to pass appropriate props between `AddEnterprise` and `ListEnterprises` in order for that to happen

Comment: @DhavalJardosh props are coming fine in AddEnterprise from ListEnterprise becuase if I am redirecting it to home("/") instead of ("/enterprises"), its is redirecting as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass callback to your AddEnterprise component to update the parent state, you can do the following.

In your parent component pass _showMessage to AddEnterprise as prop

```
{this.state.showFormMessage && (<AddEnterprise showMessage={this._showMessage}  {...this.props} />)}
```

and change your _showMessage as

```
_showMessage = (bool, update=false) => {
    this.setState({
        showFormMessage: bool
    });
    if (update) {
      this.refreshEnterprises();
    }
}
```

And in your AddEnterprise do as

```
addEnterprise(event) {
    const payload = this.state.enterprisePayload;
    EnterpriseService.addEnterprise(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, isForm: true });
            //event.peventDefault();
            this.props.showMessage(false, true); // to refresh parent call
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

In React we use state for things like these, you can't always redirect

Hope it helps

Comment: Working perfectly fine in my case. Thanks very much. As I am new to react, need to learn these concepts how different components can interact with each other.

Comment: Glad to help, I would recommend going through React docs it's very helpful https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks very much. Sure, I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Redux will be the best choice for that case but We can still do it with React alone.

You should define the `addEnterprise` function in your `EnterpriseList` component and pass it down to `AddEnterprise` component via props.

And in `addEnterprise`, call `refreshEnterprises` when the new one added successfully.